# configurations about C Programs on VS Code

Tags: c, config, vscode-tasks

I use the plugin Code Runner to develop C programs.

And the file tasks.json as follows:

```json
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: gcc.exe build active file",
            "command": "E:\\developer_tools\\C\\mingw64\\bin\\gcc.exe",
            "args": [
                "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": "build",
            "detail": "compiler: E:\\developer_tools\\C\\mingw64\\bin\\gcc.exe"
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to know how to customize the path that outputs the executive file.

Comment: You output to `"${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"` You can fully customize where you want the executable to go (e.g. some project directory, or a `./bin` directory, etc..)

Answer (score 1):

Well, the `gcc` command line is right there.

```
"-o",
"${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
```

are the parts that control where the output is written. You can customize that to your heart's liking.